# One process in my server using 100% cpu

Tags: centos, redis

Please check below

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2561 redis     20   0 2761160   2.3g   1028 S 200.0 30.0  58:33.49 sysupdate
 2576 redis     30  10  577576  61120    540 S 194.7  0.8  54:20.02 networkservice
```

I have no idea where they came from. How can I manage them

Comment: Your server was hacked. Time to clean it up.

Comment: but is my live server is there any other way

Comment: You can wait for your hosting provider to notice you've been hacked and shut down your service. This probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: why do you making fun of me?